# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Здравствуйте у меня следущая проблема :

Есть back-end сервер который написанный в Spring и работает с postgresql базой. Сначала всё работало нормально и никаких проблем не было. Но сейчас друг с которым работаем на проекте сделал sql скрипт с помощью которого мы просто записываем тестовые данные в нашу базу данных. И вот тогда у нас и случилась беда :

```
19:46:30,253 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_pkey"
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)   Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
19:46:30,255 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
19:46:30,255 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
19:46:30,255 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
19:46:30,256 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    ... 158 more
```

В том скрипте у нас также есть какие-то тестовые пользователи и эта ошибка вылетает при регистрации. Я понимаю что эта ошибка говорит что нельзя сохранить пользователя т.к. такой id в базе данных уже есть. Но загвоздка в том что я не присваиваю id для пользователя а делает это сам Hibernate. Тоисть когда я посылаю пользователя в методу save() то посылаю его без id и Hibernate сам должен присвоить ему этот id с учетом на стратегию которую я выбрал. По крайней мере я надеюсь что так оно должно работать и так оно работало до того как мы записали тестовые данные в базу данных. Но я всегда думал что когда Hibernate выбирает id то он смотрит в базе данных в таблицу или в какую-то user_id_sequence какой id был последний и берет последний + 1. И вот вопрос, почему сейчас так не происходит и Hibernate пробует сохранить пользователя с id = 1, когда в базе уже такой пользователь есть. Как это можно исправить / решить проблему ?

Если что вот так у нас стоит стратегия для генерирования id :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"deleted", "updated"})
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // ...
}
```

Конфигурация Hibernate :

```
datasource.url=**********
datasource.username=**********
datasource.password=**********
datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.batch.size=200
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Sql скрипт выглядит как обычный скрипт для наполнения :

```
INSERT INTO public.country (id, created, deleted, updated, code, name, telephone_prefix, continent_id) VALUES (101, NULL, false, NULL, 'ISR', 'Israel', 972, NULL);
....
```

Update :

Ещё хотел бы добавить что когда запускаю на пустой базе данных без тест. данных то всё работает как надо и id генерируется. Проблема только когда запускаю на базе с тест. данными.

Comment: Ты ему указал генерировать `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, а не сиквенс смотреть `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Я пробывал менять как на GenerationType.SEQUENCE так и на GenerationType.AUTO.

Comment: @Vanya GenerationType.SEQUENCE -это не sequence БД, а такой тип генератора, который указывает на нативный sequence, если в базе такой есть, в противном случае используется таблица.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="pk_sequence",sequenceName="entity_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="pk_sequence")
private Long id;
```

Правильная вставка из своих скриптов

```
INSERT INTO public.country (id, ...) VALUES (nextval('entity_id_seq'), ...);
```

Если уже навставлял своих идентификаторов, то надо выяснить максимальный вставленный

```
select max(id) from public.country
```

и заресетить сиквенс на следующий после максимального

```
ALTER SEQUENCE entity_id_seq RESTART WITH <здесь_максимальный_ИД + 1>
```

Comment: Не помогло, при попытке регистрации вылетает :

org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session :

Comment: Сиквенс не знает, что ты навставлял. Надо вставлять используя сиквенс, даже в своих скриптах или передвигать сиквенс вперёд с учётом ручных изменений `ALTER SEQUENCE entity_id_seq RESTART WITH 1000` где вместо 1000 должен стоять следующий ожидаемый номер.