# ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

я использую PostgreSQL и хочу добавлять данные в таблицу после импорта, однако у меня выходит ошибка:

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "total_pkey"
DETAIL:  Ключ "(id)=(1)" уже существует.
```

1. Я создаю таблицу SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS total (
    id serial,
    name text,
    model text,
    PRIMARY KEY( id )
);
```

2. Импортирую данные из CSV файла. Импорт происходит успешно.
3. Пытаюсь вставить новые данные

```
INSERT INTO total(qr, name, model) VALUES(00922, 'name', 'model')
```

и ошибка

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "total_pkey"
DETAIL:  Ключ "(id)=(1)" уже существует.
```

Comment: Значит неверно импортировали. А именно заполняли поле id явно-указанными значениями. Задайте новое корректное значение sequence через setval

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315255/caused-by-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-duplicate-key-value-violate/1315267#1315267